# Lantronix XPORT - TCP/IP tunnel to send HTTP POST requests

Tags: http, microcontroller, wireshark, pic, ethernet

I have a XPORT (TCP/IP serial tunnel device) connected to my microcontroller (PIC18), this way I can send serial messages which are transformed into TCP/IP packages. I've enabled TCP/IP packaging, so that all characters will be put in one TCP/IP package until nothing is received for a short period of time.

I've succesfully sent a HTTP GET request through the tcp/ip tunnel.
Though when I try to send a HTTP POST request, I either get a "400 Bad request" or my apache server crashes...

I think this behaviour is because of the line-ends not being, "right".

**My code:**

```
Delay1KTCYx(160);
xportSendTextNoLine("C192.168.200.18/80\n");//Manual connect to server (xport command)

Delay1KTCYx(160);//Wait for TCP/IP packaging.
xportSendTextNoLine("POST /debug.php HTTP/1.1");
xportSend(0x0D);//Carriage return.
xportSend(0x0A);//New line

xportSendTextNoLine("Host: 192.168.200.18");
xportSend(0x0D);//Carriage return.
xportSend(0x0A);//New line

xportSendTextNoLine("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xportSend(0x0D);//Carriage return.
xportSend(0x0A);//New line
xportSend(0x0D);//Carriage return.
xportSend(0x0A);//New line

xportSendTextNoLine("Grower=2&SiteId=99&Time=2015021108291700&Usertag=testuser&Action=0");
xportSend(0x0D);//Carriage return.
xportSend(0x0A);//New line
xportSend(0x0D);//Carriage return.
xportSend(0x0A);//New line
Delay1KTCYx(160);//Wait for TCP/IP packaging.
```

**Wireshark output (simplified):**

```
>POST /debug.php HTTP/1.1[0x0D][0x00][0x0A]
      Host: 192.168.200.18[0x0D][0x00][0x0A]
      etc.

<HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

**Wireshark output (complete):**

[image: Wireshark ouput (complete)]

It seems that a 0x0D (Carriage Return) to the Lantronix Xport causes a 0x00 to be sent after it. Which would lead to the webserver not being able to interpret the request.

I've just sent a tech support question to the Lantronix support, but I'd also like to know if **anyone can tell me if:**

- The Lantronix XPORT sends a 0x00 after a 0x0D?
- My HTTP POST request is wrong in another way? (Missing content length?)

**Verifying the output of the microcontroller:**

[image: Test 2]

**Settings of the XPORT are the same as TERMINAL and should be the same as the MCU (otherwise it wouldn't receive the same):**

[image: Settings xport]

MCU serial setup:

```
    RCSTA2bits.SPEN   = 1;   //Serial port enable
    TRISGbits.TRISG2  = 1;   //RG2 input (RX)
    TRISGbits.TRISG1  = 0;   //RG1 output (TX)
    ANCON2bits.ANSEL18= 0;   //DIGITAL!
    ANCON2bits.ANSEL19= 0;

    IPR3bits.RC2IP = 1;//High-priority  Rx interrupts
    PIE3bits.RC2IE = 1;//Enable         Rx interrupt

    TXSTA2 = 0b00100000;
    RCSTA2 = 0b10010000;
    BAUDCON2 = 0b01000000;//Receive operation active.

    SPBRG2  = 12;   // 9615 (0.16% error) (8Mhz)
```

Comment: Would this question be better asked on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange? - The reason I posted it here is because it involves networking/wireshark/http-post which would fit better here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution!

After some (logical) thinking I found that it would be the problem of the XPORT.
But what could be the problem? I disabled all features of which I thought that might interfere (even though I thought this would be unlogical to cause this kind of error) and after saving, the POST request just popped up nicely in my server...

See the settings here (might want to open it in a new tab):

[image: xport settings]